# ML.Net changing image

Tags: image-processing, ml.net

I see a lot of trainers in ML.Net that takes different data for "Features" column and for "Label" column it's mostly Single. Are there any trainers that get Vector as features and Vector as Label?
So that I can pass two images into trainer Input image and Output image that I want to get as result - and train network to change images? So next time it will "predict" output image from input image?
Or it must be done another way?